# Is there an R function for creating a new dataframe using two columns from existing dataframe?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a dataframe called cupcakes. I have three columns - one called filling, one called cake flavor, and one called sprinkle color. I want to create a new dataframe extracting just the filling and cake flavors where it counts the amount of items with each possible combination (e.g., there are 5 cupcakes I sold where there's cream filling and chocolate cake, so it prints 5 in that cell).

I would like filling to be my **rows** and cake flavor to be my **columns**. How do I accomplish this?

I tried converting the columns to a table, but it does not make one variable a column and one a row. This was my code: cakestrim <- as.data.frame(table(cakes$filling,cakes$flavor)).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ideas: `as.data.frame.matrix`, the other is the `tabyl` function from the `janitor` package.

```
cakes<-data.frame(filling=sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 20, replace=TRUE),
                  flavor=sample(c("X", "Y", "Z"), 20, replace=TRUE))
table(cakes$filling,cakes$flavor)

cakes2<-as.data.frame.matrix(table(cakes$filling,cakes$flavor))

library(janitor)
cakes3<-tabyl(cakes, filling, flavor)
```

> ```
>  filling X Y Z
>        A 1 2 3
>        B 0 1 3
>        C 4 3 3
> ```

A more complex idea, that has flexibility for advanced problems

```
library(tidyverse)
cakes %>% 
  group_by(filling, flavor) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = flavor, 
              values_from = n)
```